# Route the output of model A as the input of model B on Seldon Core

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, seldon

I'm testing Seldon Core and am wondering if there is an easy way to route the output of model A as the input of model B on Seldon Core. 
What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SeldonDeployment resource definition you have a graph section. The top-level element is the first step and it contains children for a next step. Here is a snippet [from an example](https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/issues/772) showing a transformer being used to transform a request before passing it on to a model:

```
    graph:
      children:
        - children: []
          implementation: XGBOOST_SERVER
          name: model
          modelUri: s3://model-image
          type: MODEL
      endpoint:
        type: REST
      name: feature-transformer
      type: TRANSFORMER
```

There's an [example in the seldon documentation](https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/latest/examples/kubeflow_seldon_e2e_pipeline.html#Breaking-down-the-code) where steps such as clean and tokenize are used to perform inference for natural language processing. That example has multiple steps as type MODEL. There's also [discussion on this in the seldon slack channel](https://seldondev.slack.com/archives/C8Y9A8G0Y/p1560761929110900?thread_ts=1560423848.095200&cid=C8Y9A8G0Y).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks a lot, Ryan!